# How to get the inside json from json object

Tags: javascript, json

Suppose i have this json

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

I Have the list of those objects and puting in variable like this

`var myobjects = data`

which contains list of above objects

now that is working fine butnow i have one problem. Instead of directly getting list of objects, i now have one parent object which contain those object liek this

```
"id": "21"
"myobject": 
{
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
}
```

instead of getting list of childobjects , i ow have the list of parent objects in `data`

how can get the list of child objects from list of parent objects like before

something like

`var childobjects = data.childobjects`

I want that because i ahve templates  coded which only wok if i have the direct list of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to *flatten* the array of objects?

```
// suppose data is like this:
var data = [
    { id: 1, myobject: {widgets:'',whatever:''}},
    { id: 5, myobject: {widgets:'',whatever:''}},
    { id: 23, myobject: {widgets:'',whatever:''}}
]
```

Then this code:

```
var myobjects = [];

for (key in data) {
  myobjects.push(data[key].myobject);
}
```

Will leave `myobjects` equal to:

```
[
    {widgets:'',whatever:''},
    {widgets:'',whatever:''},
    {widgets:'',whatever:''}
]
```

Comment: sorry i didn't get it. can you show  by small example , what that does. but i can be sure that i want something like that

Comment: Is it possible to insert some value like `id=34` in the widgets array to every element before making the list

Answer (score -1):

I think it's what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var parents = [{"id": "21",
                "myobject": 
                 {"widget": {
                  "debug": "on",
                  "window": {
                             "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
                              "name": "main_window",
                              "width": 500,
                              "height": 500
                             },
                "image": { 
                "src": "Images/Sun.png",
                 "name": "sun1",
                 "hOffset": 250,
                 "vOffset": 250,
                "alignment": "center"
               },
              "text": {
                      "data": "Click Here",
                      "size": 36,
                      "style": "bold",
                       "name": "text1",
                      "hOffset": 250,
                      "vOffset": 100,
                     "alignment": "center",
                     "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
                 }
             }
         }},
                {"id": "22",
                "myobject": 
                 {"widget": {
                  "debug": "on",
                  "window": {
                             "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
                              "name": "main_window",
                              "width": 500,
                              "height": 500
                             },
                "image": { 
                "src": "Images/Sun.png",
                 "name": "sun1",
                 "hOffset": 250,
                 "vOffset": 250,
                "alignment": "center"
               },
              "text": {
                      "data": "Click Here",
                      "size": 36,
                      "style": "bold",
                       "name": "text1",
                      "hOffset": 250,
                      "vOffset": 100,
                     "alignment": "center",
                     "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
                 }
             }
         }}
    ]; 
   for(x in parents ){
        console.log(parents[x].myobject);
   }
   </script>
```